# ExpandableListView & JSON

Tags: java, android, json, expandablelistview

I want to create a `ExpandableListView` with two `JSONObject`s.

The parent element shall be:

```
{"event":{"key":"world.2014","title":"World Cup 2014"},"rounds":[{"pos":1,"title":"Matchday 1","start_at":"2014/06/12","end_at":"2014/06/12"},{"pos":2,"title":"Matchday 2","start_at":"2014/06/13","end_at":"2014/06/13"},{"pos":3,"title":"Matchday 3","start_at":"2014/06/14","end_at":"2014/06/14"},{"pos":4,"title":"Matchday 4","start_at":"2014/06/15","end_at":"2014/06/15"},{"pos":5,"title":"Matchday 5","start_at":"2014/06/16","end_at":"2014/06/16"},{"pos":6,"title":"Matchday 6","start_at":"2014/06/17","end_at":"2014/06/17"},{"pos":7,"title":"Matchday 7","start_at":"2014/06/18","end_at":"2014/06/18"},{"pos":8,"title":"Matchday 8","start_at":"2014/06/19","end_at":"2014/06/19"},{"pos":9,"title":"Matchday 9","start_at":"2014/06/20","end_at":"2014/06/20"},{"pos":10,"title":"Matchday 10","start_at":"2014/06/21","end_at":"2014/06/21"},{"pos":11,"title":"Matchday 11","start_at":"2014/06/22","end_at":"2014/06/22"},{"pos":12,"title":"Matchday 12","start_at":"2014/06/23","end_at":"2014/06/23"},{"pos":13,"title":"Matchday 13","start_at":"2014/06/24","end_at":"2014/06/24"},{"pos":14,"title":"Matchday 14","start_at":"2014/06/25","end_at":"2014/06/25"},{"pos":15,"title":"Matchday 15","start_at":"2014/06/26","end_at":"2014/06/26"},{"pos":16,"title":"Round of 16","start_at":"2014/06/28","end_at":"2014/07/01"},{"pos":17,"title":"Quarter-finals","start_at":"2014/07/04","end_at":"2014/07/05"},{"pos":18,"title":"Semi-finals","start_at":"2014/07/08","end_at":"2014/07/09"},{"pos":19,"title":"Match for third place","start_at":"2014/07/12","end_at":"2014/07/12"},{"pos":20,"title":"Final","start_at":"2014/07/13","end_at":"2014/07/13"}]}
```

and the children elements:

```
{"event":{"key":"world.2014","title":"World Cup 2014"},"round":{"pos":1,"title":"Matchday 1","start_at":"2014/06/12","end_at":"2014/06/12"},"games":[{"team1_key":"bra","team1_title":"Brazil","team1_code":"BRA","team2_key":"cro","team2_title":"Croatia","team2_code":"CRO","play_at":"2014/06/12","score1":3,"score2":1,"score1ot":null,"score2ot":null,"score1p":null,"score2p":null}]}
```

and so on...
To do this, I created a `ExpandableListView`, but I´m not able to parse the **JSON Elements** right.

My Debugger shows me, that I get the JSON elements, but I don't know how to convert them right. For the elements I got

```
private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

But I don't know how to fill them in the

```
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
```

method & update the `view` in the

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
```

method.

Can you give me some suggests or examples? I searched in google for a long.

Comment: what happen that you can not parse the json? what error you got?

Comment: "Cannot parse... the problem is that I don`t know how to take "Matchday" & "Start_At" from this JSON. I want these two Strings to name my parent and Teams & Scores for child items.